# how to use url parameters in commandparameters

Tags: asp.net

i'm working on asp project and i want to use commandparameters

my question is how to put the value of controlid by using url parameter

i try this but doesnt working

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=DentistEntities" DefaultContainerName="DentistEntities" CommandText="SELECT p.[id],p.[firstName],p.[lastName],p.[DOB],p.[firstVisiting] FROM DentistEntities.Patients  AS p WHERE p.[firstName]=@firstname">
<CommandParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="firstname" ControlID='<% Request.QueryString["firstName"] %>' Type="String"/>
</CommandParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

error on page

> Could not find control '<% Request.QueryString["firstName"] %>' in ControlParameter 'firstname'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special `QueryStringParameter` for that:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="firstname" QueryStringField="firstName" Type="String"/>
```